# How to change perspective of a photo efficiently?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing, photoshop-cs6, transform

I would like to make an image look flattened on the screen as if it was 'scanned' rather than being shown at an angle.

Angle of picture taken is something similar to this :

http://www.pleasval.k12.ia.us/studyskills/j0399575.jpg

Without manually adjusting the perspective of the photo, is there a faster way to do so in Photoshop CS6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, however you will lose a lot of quality on your image. In earlier versions of PS this was done by the crop tool, but now there a new 'perspective crop' (<kbd>c</kbd>) tool.

1. Open your image
2. Choose perspective crop tool (<kbd>c</kbd>, second alternative)
3. Select an are of the image (likely to be most of the image), check 'Show grid', it helps
4. Tug at the corners of the cropping square and make sure to fit the selection to your perspective
5. Hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and the image is cropped to your new perspective

Here's a more graphical explanation: http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/perspective-crop-tool-cs6/